# GDAL - Perform Simple Least Cost Path Analysis

Tags: gdal, cost-path

I am investigating methods to perform a simple least cost path analysis with gdal.  By simple, I mean using the slope of a dem as the only cost factor.

I would prefer to do using the python or .net bindings, but will take anything.  Can anyone suggest any good tutorials or the like?

Comment: For analytical questions, perhaps better use a GIS rather than a data format abstraction library...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the application? It is difficult to think of anything for which the DEM's slope would be a realistic proxy for the cost of travel. Are you sure this is what you need? It would be a pity if, after going to the effort of writing this code, you discovered it did not actually solve your problem!

Comment: Slope could be useful as a travel cost if you're modelling a gravity-dependent dispersal model of some sort, though I'd expect some other factors too rather than just slope.

Comment: Also, slope usually shows the maximum slope at each cell, even if the route is not travelling directly downhill or uphill.

Answer (score 14):

The following script performs a least cost path analysis. Input parameters are a cost surface raster (e.g. slope) and start and stop coordinates. A raster with the created path is returned. It requires the [skimage library](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.graph.html#route-through-array) and GDAL.

The following was copied from [a very useful website](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html) for gdal related stuff.

For example the least cost path between point 1 and point 2 is created based on a slope raster:
[image]

```
import gdal, osr
from skimage.graph import route_through_array
import numpy as np


def raster2array(rasterfn):
    raster = gdal.Open(rasterfn)
    band = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
    array = band.ReadAsArray()
    return array  
    
def coord2pixelOffset(rasterfn,x,y):
    raster = gdal.Open(rasterfn)
    geotransform = raster.GetGeoTransform()
    originX = geotransform[0]
    originY = geotransform[3] 
    pixelWidth = geotransform[1] 
    pixelHeight = geotransform[5]
    xOffset = int((x - originX)/pixelWidth)
    yOffset = int((y - originY)/pixelHeight)
    return xOffset,yOffset

def createPath(CostSurfacefn,costSurfaceArray,startCoord,stopCoord):   

    # coordinates to array index
    startCoordX = startCoord[0]
    startCoordY = startCoord[1]
    startIndexX,startIndexY = coord2pixelOffset(CostSurfacefn,startCoordX,startCoordY)
    
    stopCoordX = stopCoord[0]
    stopCoordY = stopCoord[1]
    stopIndexX,stopIndexY = coord2pixelOffset(CostSurfacefn,stopCoordX,stopCoordY)
    
    # create path
    indices, weight = route_through_array(costSurfaceArray, (startIndexY,startIndexX), (stopIndexY,stopIndexX),geometric=True,fully_connected=True)
    indices = np.array(indices).T
    path = np.zeros_like(costSurfaceArray)
    path[indices[0], indices[1]] = 1
    return path

def array2raster(newRasterfn,rasterfn,array):
    raster = gdal.Open(rasterfn)
    geotransform = raster.GetGeoTransform()
    originX = geotransform[0]
    originY = geotransform[3] 
    pixelWidth = geotransform[1] 
    pixelHeight = geotransform[5]
    cols = array.shape[1]
    rows = array.shape[0]
    
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    outRaster = driver.Create(newRasterfn, cols, rows, gdal.GDT_Byte)
    outRaster.SetGeoTransform((originX, pixelWidth, 0, originY, 0, pixelHeight))
    outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
    outband.WriteArray(array)
    outRasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
    outRasterSRS.ImportFromWkt(raster.GetProjectionRef())
    outRaster.SetProjection(outRasterSRS.ExportToWkt())
    outband.FlushCache()    
    
def main(CostSurfacefn,outputPathfn,startCoord,stopCoord):
    
    costSurfaceArray = raster2array(CostSurfacefn) # creates array from cost surface raster
    
    pathArray = createPath(CostSurfacefn,costSurfaceArray,startCoord,stopCoord) # creates path array
    
    array2raster(outputPathfn,CostSurfacefn,pathArray) # converts path array to raster
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    CostSurfacefn = 'CostSurface.tif'
    startCoord = (345387.871,1267855.277)
    stopCoord = (345479.425,1267799.626)
    outputPathfn = 'Path.tif'
    main(CostSurfacefn,outputPathfn,startCoord,stopCoord)
```

Comment: I like your answer. How do you deal with e.g. lakes where the cost value is the same for a larger area. My path goes through a lake and sort of meanders around like a snake until the area is covered before it continues as expected? Thanks.

Comment: I haven't worked on this for a long time. You probably thought of this already, but I would just set the cost for the lake really high. This way the path should avoid the lake, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yeah, I set the lake to be just a bit over 0, that way there is a cost and the meandering disappears.

Comment: In general, one should drop a reference to code they copy/paste https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use the A* search algorithm using slope as the cost between generated nodes. To see a quick visualization of what that looks like:

[image: A Star Animated]

See [A* Search Algorithm (Wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*)
and
[Python A* Search Algorithm (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159331/python-speed-up-an-a-star-pathfinding-algorithm)

to understand A*.

For a slope map there are options out there - [Here](http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html#gdaldem_slope) is one.

With a slope map (raster) you can get cost values out of it with GDAL.

Comment: Can you explain how to make the slope raster to a graph so it can be used in the Python A* Search Algorithm Code you pointed out? I know how to get the value out of the raster with GDAL. but as what shall I store it in order to use it as a graph (e.g. Dictionary?)?